# Djangoでauth.Userモデルを拡張したい

Tags: python, django

Django1.7で、AbstractUserを使ってauth.Userモデルに新たにユーザー区分というフィールドを追加したいと考えています。以下のアドレスを参考にし、その通りに実装してみました。http://nihaoshijie.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2014/06/11/165258

models.py(抜粋)

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   userclass = models.CharField(u'ユーザ区分', max_length=50,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):    # Python2: def __unicode__(self):
        return self.userclass

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.userclass)
```

setting.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appointment.CustomUser'
```

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(CustomUser)
```

しかしながらmodels.pyのUserモデルでAuthUserとForeignKeyで結びつけているために以下のようなエラーが表示されました。

```
appointment.User.authuser: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
```

models.py(別の部分)

```
class User(models.Model):#define user
    authuser = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser,verbose_name = u'ゲスト')
```

出来うる限りこのユーザモデルは改変せずこのエラーを解決したいです。どうかご教授お願いします。